# Basic input validation package in Lua

Tags: beginner, validation, lua

I'm very new to Lua (and programming in general). I wanted to start out with a simple package that validates input based on a set of rules.

The code works as intended, but is what I have written is any good? I'd love to hear your feedback!

**`validator.lua`**

```
--- An input validation package written in Lua.
-- @module validator
local validator = {}

--- Local table that holds all validation functions.
-- @within rules
local rules = {}

--- Check if input holds a value.
-- @param input The input to check.
-- @return True if a input holds a value, false and error otherwise.
-- @within rules
function rules.required(input)
    if (type(input) == "string" and input:len() == 0) or
       (type(input) == "table" and not next(input))
    then
        return false, "%s has no value"
    end
    return true
end

--- Check if string or number length is greater than or equal to a given size.
-- @param input The input to check.
-- @param size The minimum size.
-- @return True if input is at least the given size, false and error otherwise.
-- @within rules
function rules.min(input, size)
    if (type(input) == "string" and input:len() < size) or
       (type(input) == "number" and input < size)
    then
        return false, "%s must be a minimum of "..size 
    end
    return true
end

--- Check if string or number length is less than or equal to a given size.
-- @param input The input to check.
-- @param size The maximum size.
-- @return True if input is at most the given size, false and error otherwise.
-- @within rules
function rules.max(input, size)
    if (type(input) == "string" and input:len() > size) or
       (type(input) == "number" and input > size)
    then
        return false, "%s must be a maximum of "..size
    end
    return true
end

--- Check if string only contains letters.
-- @param input The input to check.
-- @return True if input only contains letters, false and error otherwise.
-- @within rules
function rules.alpha(input)
    if input:find("%A") then
        return false, "%s must be alphabetic"
    end
    return true
end

--- Check if string only contains digits.
-- @param input The input to check.
-- @return True if input only contains digits, false and error otherwise.
-- @within rules
function rules.int(input)
    if input:find("%D") then
        return false, "%s must be a number"
    end
    return true
end

--- Check if string only contains letters or digits.
-- @param input The input to check.
-- @return True if input only contains letters or digits, false and error otherwise.
-- @within rules
function rules.alnum(input)
    if input:find("%W") then
        return false, "%s must be alphanumeric"
    end
    return true
end

function rules.__index()
    error("Trying to validate with non-existant rule")
end

--- Extracts all rules from a string.
-- @param[opt] rules_string The string of rules.
-- @return Table with all the rules.
-- @usage extract_rules("required|min(12)") --> {"required", "min(12)"}
local function extract_rules(rules_string)
    local rules = {}
    if rules_string then
        for rule in rules_string:gmatch("[^|]+") do
            table.insert(rules, rule)
        end
    end
    return rules
end

--- Extracts the argument from a rule.
-- @param rule The rule to extract the argument from.
-- @return The name of the rule, and the argument or nil
-- @usage extract_rule_arg("min(12)") --> "min", 12
-- @usage extract_rule_arg("required") --> "required", nil
local function extract_rule_arg(rule)
    local func_name = rule:match("%a+")
    local func_arg = rule:match("%((.+)%)")
    func_arg = tonumber(func_arg) or func_arg
    return func_name, func_arg
end

--- Validate using input and rules
-- @param inputs A table of inputs
-- @param inputs_rules A table of rules
-- @return True if validation passes, false and table with errors otherwise.
function validator.validate(inputs, inputs_rules)
    local errors = {}
    local has_errors = false

    for field, input in pairs(inputs) do
        errors[field] = {}
        local input_rules = extract_rules(inputs_rules[field])
        for _, input_rule in pairs(input_rules) do
            local rule_func_name, rule_arg = extract_rule_arg(input_rule)
            local is_valid, err = rules[rule_func_name](input, rule_arg)
            if not is_valid then
                has_errors = true
                table.insert(errors[field], err:format(field))
            end
        end
    end

    if has_errors then
        return false, errors
    end
    return true
end

return validator
```

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
local validator = require("validator")

local inputs = {
    username = "CodeReviewer",
    password = "Password123",
}

local rules = {
    username = "required|min(3)|max(20)",
    password = "required|min(8)|max(99)",
}

local is_valid, errors = validator.validate(inputs, rules)

if is_valid then
    -- Success!
else
    for field, field_errors in pairs(errors) do
        print("> "..field)
        for i=1, #field_errors do print(field_errors[i]) end
    end
end
```

Any input would be highly appreciated! I want to focus on becoming a better programmer in any way I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the example you provided with some invalid rules. The output I receive is:

```
> username
> password
password must be a minimum of 12
password must be a maximum of 6
```

which to me appears to mean that there was **some** error in the `username` field, but was not propagated to the errors list.

Instead of creating `errors[field]` table for all `field`s, create it lazily:

```
if not is_valid then
    has_errors = true
    place_error(errors, field, err)
end
```

and the helper:

```
local function place_error(error_list, field, template)
    if error_list[field] == nil then
       error_list[field] = {}
    end
    --- can also write
    -- error_list[field] = error_list[field] or {}
    table.insert(error_list[field], template:format(field))
end
```

---

The function name `extract_rule_arg` should only extract the argument from a rule, but it returns 2 values; which is an anti-pattern imo. Rename it to for eg. `parse_rule` or just `get_rule`.

---

Based on current patterns parsing, you are considering `|min_max_2134(12)` to be the same as `|min(12)`. It should instead raise error for the same.

```
local name, arg = rule:match "[^(]+%s*%((.+)%)"
```

and for the `required` and other such similar rules, the next line:

```
if rules[rule] then name = rule end
```

should be enough. Although, in this method; you'd be again discarding of another imaginary no-arg based rule: `a|min(x)` since `rules['a']` does not exist. If you really want to raise errors for such cases, you can chose to force your `rule` to become the name:

```
name = name or rule
```

putting that all together:

```
local function parse_rule(rule)
    local name, arg = rule:match "([^(]+)%s*%((.+)%)"
    if rules[rule] then name = rule end
    name = name or rule
    arg = tonumber(arg) or arg
    return name, arg
    -- or you may choose to return the function if you rename
    -- the function as `get_rule` for eg.
    -- return rules[name], arg
end
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed. I will update my code to include your suggestions. Thank you for taking the time to review my code.